# varchar data type doesn't accept character from data dump

Tags: mysql, sql

My import query doesn't push through because a certain special chinese character in my data dump interferes with the command. It says "#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xDA?????...' for column 'Description' at row 1"

the description field is currently a varchar type with a length of (5000). What do you think causes this problem? Are there perhaps a problem with the content of the dump? Are there special characters that are incompatible to this varchar data type? Are there workarounds or fix for this?

Comment: There's a wrong encoding somewhere: the file doesn't have the encoding you think, your connection has not been established with the correct encoding, table/column is set to a wrong encoding... Since you don't mention what your encoding you're supposed to be using, perhaps you're just running the import with whatever defaults everything has.

Comment: the file is an xls file which I have saved as a csv. then I imported using phpmyadmin console. therefore I am using the default encoding I think. I tried using nvarchar but there is no option for that.. I tried editing the "collation" or the encoding for that field to utf8mb4 but im not sure if that wil work.

Comment: One easy way to fix encoding issue is opening the file with HxD editor or similar and get rid of the bom character manually, if of course, it is just one time thing. Otherwise you have to explain which encoding are you using

Comment: If you export from XLS to CSV in LibreOffice you get a dialog to choose an encoding, but if you export with Microsoft Excel it picks one for you and the actual value depends on the configuration of the operating system.

Comment: the encoding used is latin1_swedish_ci.. there's a lot of data so I can't do manual editing on my end.. the dump consists of data from a lot of languages hence the descriptions contain a lot of different characters. I'll try editing this encoding or the data type from mysql console instead of the phpmyadmin console and see what happens

Comment: It is in row one, normally with excel to csv it is the first character. I know because happened to me billions of time, working with huge massive file. HxD can open massive file with no issue. You will see something wired at the beginning, just get rid of it.

Comment: oh @ÁlvaroGonzález is that so? well that's cool to know. I might as well try using LibreOffice then, that might be the problem

Comment: I'll try that @MiloBellano

Comment: In any case, you should inspect the CSV in a regular text editor with encoding support in order to figure out what encoding it may be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update on the problem. I actually was able to fix it by using only standard notepad to convert the csv file's character encoding to utf8. I also changed the table and database defaults to utf8. After that, only minor modifications to the data type lengths and I was able to completely import the data. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use nvarchar instead of varchar and ensure your input data is in the same encoding as your database.

EDIT: Just noticed the mysql tag; you should use "character set utf8" in your column declaration.

Comment: In MySQL `NVARCHAR` is supposedly an alias for `VARCHAR` with `utf8` encoding (just learnt it yesterday, I haven't really tried it).

Comment: I tried it using phpmyadmin however it appears that the nvarchar option is not available.